# Alias for redirecting both standard output and standard error, as well as sending to background

Tags: shell, io-redirection, alias, background-process

I am trying to create an `alias` for redirecting both standard output and standard error of `gedit` to `/dev/null`, whilst sending the command to background.

This works:

```
$ alias gedit='gedit $1 > /dev/null 2>&1'
$ gedit file.txt &
```

However, adding the background instruction `&` to the `alias` string fails to work because it gets immediately interpreted:

```
$ alias gedit='gedit $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
[1]+  Done                    gedit > /dev/null 2>&1
```

How should I add this `&` background instruction to the `alias` command?

Comment: Is this for `bash`?

Comment: @Timo This would be for use in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with an `alias`, but you can with a function in Bash.

```
$ gedit() { command gedit "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 & }
```

#### Example

```
$ gedit file.txt
[1] 24057
$
```

#### Details

The function makes use of Bash's `command` command. This will invoke the actual executable with a given name, rather than call any aliases or functions that already exist. I opted to use `$@` instead which will give you all the command line arguments passed instead of just the first with `$1`.

Comment: I used this to create a general purpose `start` function, it's basically the same except it accepts any program and its argument: `start(){ command $@ &> /dev/null & }`, it then can be called like `start gedit myFile`.